# Tree Diagram Spacing Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am having trouble fixing the spacing of my tree.

Currently, I have the following code and result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

    % Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=4cm, sibling distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=4cm, sibling distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=20mm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em,text centered]

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,->,>=angle 60, sloped]
%\begin{scope}[yshift=0]
  \node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {Testing Consumer $t=0$}
    child {
        node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {$E[u(c,l,\eta_1)|K]$}
         edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 0$}
    }
    child {node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {t=1 $E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|K]$ }
      child {node{$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|\eta_0]$}
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 0$}
        }
      child {node[bag, minimum width=4cm] {$E[u(c',l',\eta_k)|K]$}
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 1$}
        }
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 1$}
    }
        
        ;
%\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I hope to have a neater image, with more spacing in the labels of the child nodes as well. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome! Please can you make your code compilable? Off-topic: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Consider using `\tikzset` instead. Are you open to solutions using other packages?

Comment: The base TikZ tree methods are really not ideal for most trees. For this sort of of tree either `forest` (general purpose) or `istgame` (designed specifically for game trees) is a much better choice.

Comment: @cfr Yes I am fully open to other packages. As long as they allow me to work with probability and dynamic diagrams such as this one. I also updated the code to make it compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe like this ?
I replaced deprecated `\tikzstyle`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% tikzset instead of deprecated tikzstyle
\tikzset{
    level 1/.style={level distance=4cm, sibling distance=6cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=4cm, sibling distance=3cm},
    level 3/.style={level distance=3cm, sibling distance=2cm},
    bag/.style={text width=8em, text centered}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,->,>=angle 60, sloped]
  \node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {Testing Consumer $t=0$}
    child {
        node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {$E[u(c,l,\eta_1)|K]$}
         edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 0$}
    }
    child {node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {t=1 $E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|K]$ }
      child {node{$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|\eta_0]$}
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 0$}
        }
      child {node[bag, minimum width=2cm] {$E[u(c',l',\eta_k)|K]$}
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 1$}
        }
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$\kappa = 1$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


  [1]:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0X1o.png

Answer (score 3):

I would use `forest`, though `istgame` would also be a great choice. Possibly something like this?

```
\begin{forest}
  align=center,
```

This is just for the root node. Children's alignment is handled below.

```
  for tree={%
    grow'=east,
    calign=midpoint,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    anchor=child anchor,
```

Basically, align parents with the point halfway between their children, align children on the same level according to their `child anchor`s and set the growth direction and anchors for the tree. This also ensures the branching edges start from a common point, which seems to be usual for probability/game trees.

```
    l sep'+=25pt,
```

Increase the distance between levels i.e. between each parent and its children. This may not be sufficient.

```
    s sep'+=20pt,
```

Increase the minimum separation between siblings.

```
    edge+={-Stealth},
```

Add an arrow to all edges.

```
    font=\sffamily,
```

Use sans for text. This is usually a good idea for diagrams, but you may or may not want it in this case given the high ratio of maths to text.

```
  },
  for descendants={%
```

The following affects all descendants i.e. everything except the root.

```
    if n=1{edge label={node[above,midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize]{$\kappa=1$}}}{
      edge label={node[below,midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize]{$\kappa=0$}},
    },
```

If we're dealing with the first child, set the edge label to `$\kappa=1$` and put it above the line; if the second, use `$\kappa=0` and set it below.

```
    align=left,
```

Alignment for these nodes. Use `center` here if preferred.

```
  },
```

Finally, the tree itself. I've broken lines manually because it is easier to get a neat result and there aren't many to do.

```
  [{Testing\\Consumer\\$t=0$}
    [{t=1\\$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|K]$}
      [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_k)|K]$}
      ]
      [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|\eta_0]$}
      ]
    ]
    [{$E[u(c,l,\eta_1)|K]$}
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Be aware that I cannot currently produce images of output which are worth squat due to an Okular/KDE bug. So my output looks fine in the PDF, but sucks when I post it here.

[image: tree with forest]

I'm not certain what the `t=0` etc. designate. If these apply to all nodes on a level, I'd put these markers either above or below the tree instead. For example, you could add something like

```
  before typesetting nodes={%
    tikz+={\coordinate (c) at ([yshift=5pt]current bounding box.north);},
    tempcounta/.max={level}{tree},
    for nodewalk={%
      do while={>OR<{level}{tempcounta}}{fake=next node},
      current and ancestors
    }{%
      tikz+/.process={Ow{level}{%
          \node [anchor=base] at ( |- c) {$t=#1$};
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

to the preamble to create labels for the levels at the top.

[image: labels for each level at the top]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713428/ addaswyd o gwestiwn MarV: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713292/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  align=center,
  for tree={%
    grow'=east,
    calign=midpoint,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    anchor=child anchor,
    l sep'+=25pt,
    s sep'+=20pt,
    edge+={-Stealth},
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  for descendants={%
    if n=1{edge label={node[above,midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize]{$\kappa=1$}}}{
      edge label={node[below,midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize]{$\kappa=0$}},
    },
    align=left,
  },
  [{Testing\\Consumer\\$t=0$}
    [{t=1\\$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|K]$}
      [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_k)|K]$}
      ]
      [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|\eta_0]$}
      ]
    ]
    [{$E[u(c,l,\eta_1)|K]$}
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  align=center,
  for tree={%
    grow'=east,
    calign=midpoint,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    anchor=child anchor,
    l sep'+=25pt,
    s sep'+=20pt,
    edge+={-Stealth},
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  for descendants={%
    if n=1{edge label={node[above,midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize]{$\kappa=1$}}}{
      edge label={node[below,midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize]{$\kappa=0$}},
    },
    align=left,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    tikz+={\coordinate (c) at ([yshift=5pt]current bounding box.north);},
    tempcounta/.max={level}{tree},
    for nodewalk={%
      do while={>OR<{level}{tempcounta}}{fake=next node},
      current and ancestors
    }{%
      tikz+/.process={Ow{level}{%
          \node [anchor=base] at ( |- c) {$t=#1$};
        }
      },
    },
  },
  [{Testing\\Consumer}
    [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|K]$}
      [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_k)|K]$}
      ]
      [{$E[u(c',l',\eta_{k,1})|\eta_0]$}
      ]
    ]
    [{$E[u(c,l,\eta_1)|K]$}
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: @JeT Yours does the job and was delivered faster!